# What should be written after an Umlaut (ck or k)?

Tags: spelling

So after vowels in the German language you should write `ck` and after other letters you should write just `k`. So I was wondering, because Umlauts are the vowels but modified a bit, should you write `ck` or `k` after an Umlaut?

Comment: Who told you that rule? It's wrong.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I didn't mean you ALWAYS write ck after vowels, but for the times when you have a word like "Stock" (floor/story) it's `ck` because `o` is a vowel.

Comment: No, it's more complicated like that. I write an answer about it.

Comment: Just a [quote](https://www.deutsche-grammatik.net/rechtschreibung/verdoppelung-von-konsonanten/):  _Nach einem kurzen Vokal wird ein Konsonant in der Regel verdoppelt_  The rule is for short vowels, not for vowels in general. And  there may be exeptions,

Comment: @Pollitzer The language definitely isn't easy but it's not a random mess

Comment: (except Genetiv, Genetiv doesn't even sound German)

Comment: @knut I'd appreciate if [people who publish orthographic rules on the internet](https://www.deutsche-grammatik.net/rechtschreibung/verdoppelung-von-konsonanten/) published rules that actually work. Hint: We do **not** write "Nach ein**e**mm kurz**e**nn V**o**ckal wird ein Kons**o**nnant **i**nn d**e**rr Reg**e**ll v**e**rrdoppelt", even though the bold vowels are clearly short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that ck is always written after a vowel. As a general rule, ck is written after a **short** vowel, as in *Sack*, *Socke*, *Puck*. After a long vowel k is used. This is less frequent, but examples of it exist, e.g. *blöken*, *häkeln*.

There are exceptions to this rule, e.g. *Paket*. Even native speakers of German sometimes get this wrong and mistakenly write *Packet* because of the short *a*.

Since umlauts can be short or long, they can be followed by ck or k, although the former is more frequent.

Comment: The *Paket* mystery is easily solved. It's *Pa-ket*. The *k* belongs to the second syllable, so it cannot have an influence on the *a*. In contrary, in *Päckchen (Päck-chen)*, the *k* belongs to the first syllable, so it has to be *ck* to mark a short *ä*.

Comment: As a general rule, "ck" is written after a **short stressed** vowel (just like the other double consonants "bb", "dd", "ff", "gg", "ll", "mm", "nn", "pp", "rr", "ss", "tt", "tz").

Comment: @Janka: The same could be said in the case of *Hacke*, *Backe*, *Socke* and many more. Hence, the answer is correct to label *Paket* an exception. The claim that the 'k' sound from the second syllable "cannot have an influence on the *a*" is downright incorrect.

Comment: In your examples, ck(kk) is at the syllable boundary. It belongs to both syllables.

Comment: In "Paket", the "a" is short but *unstressed*, therefore it's not followed by a double consonant. Same as in "Banane", "Garage", "Kanone", "Kanüle", "Rakete", "Salat", "Tabelle", "Talent". This is not an exception at all.

Comment: @Janka: I'm not convinced. When you split a word like *Hacke* and pronounce it syllable-wise, you get "ha - ke", not "hak - ke" or anything like that. In that respect, *Hacke* and *Paket* behave precisely the same way. Uwe's remark about the rule not applying to unstressed syllables sounds more likely, though.

Comment: Do you really think the first syllable of *Ralle* and *Rappe* ends the same? I don't.

Comment: @Janka: I do. The first syllable is [ʀa] in both cases.